Map Series - Calculating Sq Ft of easement within Parcel
I am using ArcGIS Pro and I have it set up where parcels are the set pages.
Basically, I have a few easements running through the parcels. For whatever parcel/page I am on I want the acreage to show at the bottom. So, I want to know how much of transportation easement and pipeline easement for example are within THAT ONE parcel.
Can this be done without splitting the easements at parcel lines?
